# Не подключается библиотека commctrl.h

Tags: c++, winapi

Пытаюсь подключить commctrl.h, на это получаю ошибку:

Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ.

windows.h подключен, в интернете прочитал, что нужно Windows SDK установить, но это не помогает.

Подскажи, пожалуйста, что еще сделать можно?

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки компиляции. Какой именно символ не найден? Не забыли ли Comctl32.lib? А лучше, приведите  минимальный пример воспроизводящий ошибку.

Comment: Просто пытаюсь ее прицепить к файлу, подключаю windows.h, затем  commctrl.h, даже не вызываю функции оттуда.

Comment: `commctrl.h` - это не библиотека, это заголовочный файл, а вам еще надо соответствующую библиотеку подключить.